# A confusion on Varna and its classification

Tags: caste-system, varna, gunas, varnashrama, caste

I am confused about Varna is it birth or guna-based? Also, what's the difference between bodily and mental gunas? Also, what are the 5 types of Brahmins mentioned in the Mahabharata: 'Those Brahmanas, O king, that are possessed of learning and beneficent features, and that look upon all creatures with an equal eye, are said to be equal to Brahma. They that are conversant with the Riches, the Yajuses and the Samans, and who are devoted to the practices of their order, are, O king, equal to the very gods. Those, however, amongst them that are not well-born and not devoted to the duties of their order, and are, besides wedded to evil practices, are like Sudras. A virtuous king should realise tribute from and impress without pay into the public service those Brahmanas that are not possessed of Vedic lore and that have not their own fires to worship. They that are employed in courts of justice for summoning people, they that perform worship for others for a fee, they that perform the sacrifices of Vaisyas and Sudras, they that officiate in sacrifices on behalf of a whole village, and they that make voyages on the ocean,—these five are regarded as Candalas among Brahmanas."

Is there any scripture with a clear, concise, and authoritative explanation of Varna from a dharmacharya or one from a Vishsitadvaitan? Please give links and authoritative sources for my further reading.